# How to get count of visible points on LineChart in AChartEngine

Tags: android, achartengine

Is there any method which can give me the count of visible points (Not all points) in AChartEngine ?

Example : If I have total 20 points but only 5 will display initially rest will shown when user will do panning or zooming.
So the result would be 5 but when I zoom out there will be 10 points visible so this time the result would be 10.

Is there any method using which I can achieve this ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't such a method, but you can compute this value yourself in a quite easy manner. You can get the X and Y axis visible area by calling `renderer.getXAxisMin()`, `renderer.getXAxisMax()` and similar `renderer.getYAxisMin()`, `renderer.getYAxisMax()`.

Then, you can iterate over the items in your series and check if it is inside the visible ranges above.